# How to initialize many local variables in C++

Tags: c++, variables

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//Declares the prototype of function half().
float half1(float num1, float halfvalue1);
float half2(float num2, float halfvalue2);
float half3(float num3, float halfvalue3);

int main()
{
    //Declares variables
    float num1, num2, num3, halfvalue1, halfvalue2, halfvalue3;
    //asks for values
    cout << "Enter 3 real numbers and I will display their halves: " << endl << endl;
    //stores values
    cin >> num1, num2, num3;
    //return half and assign result to halfvalue
    halfvalue1 = half1(num1, 2.0);
    halfvalue2 = half2(num2, 2.0);
    halfvalue3 = half3(num3, 2.0);
    //set precision
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision (3);
    //Prints message with results
    cout << halfvalue1 << halfvalue2 << halfvalue3 << " are the halves of " << num1 << num2 << num3 << endl;

    return 0;
}

//function definition half
float half1(float num1, float halfvalue1)
{
    return num1 / halfvalue1;
}

float half2(float num2, float halfvalue2)
{
    return num2 / halfvalue2;
}

float half3(float num3, float halfvalue3)
{
    return num3 / halfvalue3;
}
```

The warnings are:

> warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'num2' used
>   warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'num3' used

I had full success when I was just using one variable but now I am unsure how to fix that problem.

Comment: Uh, is there a reason you are using *terrifyingly redundant* functions? Or giving each of them an argument for "halfvalue", despite that always being 2.0 by definition?

Comment: I know it looks really ugly but somehow I made it work so I just stuck with it. If you could offer a simpler way to write that, don't hesitate to help out.

Comment: Yes. Replace them all with a single function: `float half(float num) { return num / 2.0; }`. Call it much the same way you do now, except leaving out the `2.0` parameter. This is not merely simpler, but a good practice in general; if you have a function that does a particular thing, make sure you only have to change the code in one place to fix any mistakes or add anything to it.

Comment: In that case would I need to be using double instead of float?

Comment: I don't see why, but if you feel like, change the literal to include a trailing `f` to coerce it to be a float.

Comment: When I try using the single function am I supposed to declare num and halfvalue as well as the other variables?

Comment: Nope. Call it like `half(num1)`, `half(num2)`, and so forth. The names of the function's arguments do not need to match the names of the parameters you pass in, and arguments need no other variable declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `cin >> num1,num2,num3;` evaluates to three separate expressions:

1. `cin >> num1`
2. `num2` (discarded because there are no side effects)
3. `num3` (also discarded)

The commas are taken as operators, not an initializer list.

Try this instead:

```
cin >> num1;
cin >> num2;
cin >> num3;
```

or this:

```
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
```

Comment: yeah i'm just waiting for the 10 minutes to pass so I can do that

Comment: You could also use: `cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - Yes, thank you, and I edited to reflect that. I only used the first example for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed, error is in `cin >> num1, num2, num3;` with comma operator.

Using array may clean code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

float half(float num)
{
    return num / 2;
}

int main()
{
    // Declares variables
    float nums[3]; // or std::array<float, 3> nums; or std::vector<float> nums(3);
    float halfvalues[3];

    //asks for values
    std::cout << "Enter 3 real numbers and I will display their halves: " << std::endl
              << std::endl;
    //stores values
    for (auto& v : nums) {
        std::cin >> v;
    }
    //return half and assign result to halfvalue
    std::transform(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums), std::begin(halfvalues), &half);

    //set precision
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision (3);
    //Prints message with results
    for (const auto& v : halfvalues) {
        std::cout << " " << v;
    }
    std::cout << " are the halves of ";
    for (const auto& v : nums) {
        std::cout << " " << v;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/FUzxZJ)